# Issue while Configuring color swatches in Magento 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I am using Magento 1.9.2.10 to configure color swatches i have followed the below link to do this:

> https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-and-manage-configurable-swatches.html#gref

but i'm  getting following error in my frontend and no products are loading:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Queldorei_ShopperSettings_Helper_Mediafallback::attachProductChildrenAttributeMapping()
>   in
>   C:\wamp64\www\shopping_hub\app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Model\Observer.php
>   on line 59

when i disable my configurable options from configuration section in admin panel then products are displayed but i also want color swatches to simultaneously.
I found this link

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321588/magento1-9-3-3-configurable-product-swatch-bug but it did'nt work. Please help to sort out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's an error from the shopper theme.
Either contact their support or post the full helper method so that someone can try and see what the bug is.